# Get complex object using IN equivalent in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of type customer. I need to insert all values of the list in the database before checking if a customer with the same customer number exists for that particular client.
For that I am firing a query to get me all customers who are there in the database having customer number equal to ones in the list. The query I am writing is not working, here's the code.

```
CustomerRepository.Find(x => x.ClientId == clientId)
            .Where(x => x.CustomerNumber.Contains(lstCustomersInserted.Select(c => c.CustomerNumber)));
```

Comment: Tell us what is specifically going wrong.

Comment: What type is `x.CustomerNumber`?  You probably want to do `lstCustomersInserted.Contains(x.CustomerNumber)`

Comment: Your system dynamic is making some noise when you running this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
var lstCustomerNumbers = lstCustomersInserted.Select(c => c.CustomerNumber);    
var res = CustomerRepository.Where(x => x.ClientId == clientId && lstCustomerNumbers.Any(c => c == x.CustomerNumber));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have it backwards. Try reversing the Contains.

Edit: I switched to using the generic predicate Exists instead of Contains based on the comment, so you can match a property.

```
CustomerRepository.Find(x => x.ClientId == clientId)
            .Where(x => lstCustomersInserted.Exists(c => x.CustomerNumber == c.CustomerNumber));
```

Comment: That's not how `Contains` works.  It should just be `lstCustomersInserted.Contains(x.CustomerNumber)`.  That or change it to `Any`.

Comment: fixed. I just didn't actually run the code locally to verify the particular method signature.

Comment: Note that if `lstCustomersInserted` is a `List<T>` then there is a native `Contains` vs using the Linq `Contains`, If it isn't a list then `Exists` will not work.  Best to use `Contains` to cover all possible implementations.

Comment: but it's a list of complex objects, not a list of simple strings. contains will not work either. CustomerNumber is a property of the object in the list, as well as a property of the object in the IQueryable, at least that's what I'm understanding from the original question.

Answer (score 0):

How about an `Except`?

```
CustomerRepository.Select(x => x.ClientID)
                  .Except(lstCustomersInserted.Select(x => x.CustomerID));
```

This will return the IDs of the objects in the repo that don't exist in your `lstCustomersInserted`.